# AWS Firehose and Go Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am trying to send a simple file to Firehose in Go and keep getting:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x4015b7]

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x8b9260, 0xc82000a0e0)
    /usr/lib/go-1.6/src/runtime/panic.go:481 +0x3e6
main.main()
    /home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/user/proj/txtParser.go:68 +0x5b7
exit status 2
```

below is the small script

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/firehose"
"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
"io/ioutil"
"log"   
)

func main() {

  sess := session.Must(session.NewSession())

  svc := firehose.New(sess)

  firehoseData, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/tmp/adsDat1")

  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

  var rec *firehose.Record

  var recInput *firehose.PutRecordInput

  rec.SetData(firehoseData)
  recInput.SetDeliveryStreamName("test-ads-txt")
  recInput.SetRecord(rec)

  res, err1 := svc.PutRecord(recInput)

  if err1 != nil {
   log.Fatal(err1)
  }
  fmt.Println(res)
}
```

Any ideas on what is going on I am sure it is something quite simple but I have been staring at this for too long and can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: What is `txtParser.go:68`?

Comment: You only have 40 lines in `txtParser.go` so how can there be a problem on line 68?

Comment: I removed the comments from it so it screwed up the line count it is this line it references: res, err1 := svc.PutRecord(recInput)

Comment: txtParser.go is just the file name of this file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I declared my variable using a pointer of the type instead of declaring my variable with the type. See how it should be below

```
 var rec firehose.Record

 var recInput firehose.PutRecordInput
```

also added the address into these instead of the variable

```
 recInput.SetRecord(&rec)

 res, err1 := svc.PutRecord(&recInput)
```

and it works.